I had the error in gpt ai,while fetching answers from ai
sql memory.py:
class SqlMessageHistory(BaseChatMessageHistory, BaseModel):
    conversation_id: str

    @property
    def messages(self):
        return get_messages_by_conversation_id(self.conversation_id)
    
    def add_message(self, message):
        return add_message_to_conversation(
            conversation_id=self.conversation_id,
            role=message.type,
            content=message.content
        )

get_message_by_coversation_id:
def get_messages_by_conversation_id(
    conversation_id: str,
) -> AIMessage | HumanMessage | SystemMessage:
    """
    Finds all messages that belong to the given conversation_id

    :param conversation_id: The id of the conversation

    :return: A list of messages
    """
    messages = (
        db.session.query(Message)
        .filter_by(conversation_id=conversation_id)
        .order_by(Message.created_on.desc())
    )
    return [message.as_lc_message() for message in messages]

I got this error:

File "C:\Users\user.virtualenvs\pdf-_5fqVfLW\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\conversational_retrieval\base.py", line 146, in _call
chat_history_str = get_chat_history(inputs["chat_history"])


File "C:\Users\user.virtualenvs\pdf-_5fqVfLW\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\conversational_retrieval\base.py", line 43, in _get_chat_history
for dialogue_turn in chat_history:

TypeError: 'property' object is not iterable

